# Immutable object is not being set in state

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

The immutable object being returned is correct but `this.setState({...})` does not seem to set it.

I've tried the various ways to set state and all seem to have failed.

```
  state = {
    onboarding3: fromJS({
      selection: {
        neverBeen: false,
        noConvert: false,
        both: false
      },
      noConvertOptions: {
        dynamicCreative: false,
        noPurchase: false,
        abandoned: false
      },
      bothOptions: {
        dynamicCreative: false,
        noPurchase1: false,
        noPurchase2: false
      }
    })
  };
```

```
  updateToggle = (field, option) => {
    return () => {
      const currentValue = this.state.onboarding3.getIn([field, option]);
      const onboarding3 = this.state.onboarding3.setIn([field, option], !currentValue);

      this.setState({ onboarding3 });
    };
  };
```

```
<Component
    roundedSwitchFunc={this.updateToggle("noConvertOptions", "dynamicCreative")}
    defaultChecked={onboarding3.getIn(["noConvertOptions", "dynamicCreative"])}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue of event bubbling and the data not being in sync. The purpose of this component was for my state to mimic the store but since each component has their own 'store', it does not accurately mimic Redux.